# How to increase keyboard light with Touch Bar not working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, touch-bar

My Touch Bar recently stopped working and at this point I have stopped trying to fix it.. I have tried reseting SMC/NVRAM. I just wanted to know if there is a way to turn on the keyboard lights even without Touch Bar working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to manually adjust the keyboard backlight without the Touch Bar working, but you can set it to automatically turn on in low light:

[Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202310):

> **Adjust the brightness automatically**
>
> To set your keyboard brightness to
> adjust automatically:
>
> 1. From the Apple menu, choose System Preferences,
>    then click Keyboard.
> 2. Select the "Adjust keyboard brightness in low
>    light" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it now via **Control Center** on Big Sur (macos 11)

[image]

If there is no *keyboard brightness* option you can customize the Control Center in the Dock & Menu Bar pane of System Preferences.